# jQuery, get variable from outside of the function

Tags: jquery, variables

I have following jQuery example:

```
$('li.mega').mouseover(function() {
    var megaTrue = 1;
});

$('li.mega').mouseout(function() {
    var megaTrue = 0;
});
```

and than

```
function functionName() {

        if( megaTrue == 1 ) {

             //do something

        } else {

            //do nothing
            return false;   

        }               
    }
```

But `megaTrue` will be undefined, is there something like a GLOBAL variable in jQuery?

All suggestion much appreciated.

Comment: Just defining the variable outside of the functions should do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but it's very rarely a good idea to use globals: this is true in Javascript as much as anywhere. The semantic, meaningful place to store data is with the element itself. jQuery supports this with the [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) method:

```
$('li.mega').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).data('mousedOver', true);
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).data('mousedOver', false);
});
```

If you have many `li.mega` elements and you don't care which one is moused over, you could set the value on the parent element:

```
$('li.mega').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).parent().data('mousedOver', true);
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).parent().data('mousedOver', false);
});
```

---

Sorry, missed a crucial step: checking the value.  You can then get the value off the element using the `data` method like this:

```
if ($('li.mega').data('mousedOver')) {
```

Comment: OK, but `if(mousedOver)` is still `undefined`. As it is in different function.

Comment: Considering that this will be stored in the $.cache-Object, where are the advantages to that, apart from a little less clutter (yet more complex code)?

Comment: Or do I need to check `.data` for `mousedOver`? if yes, how?

Comment: @NewUser That's because it doesn't set a global value: see my edit.

Comment: @lonesomeday - yes, I knew something was missing. Thanks for you help.

Comment: @m90 It's semantic and meaningful rather than cluttering up the global namespace. That seems like a good thing to me.

Comment: Hmm.. still undefined. Give me a minute, will create a fiddle.

Comment: Default without changes: http://progrees.pl/test1/ , and nearly working. http://progrees.pl/test2/ `if you hover on link2 first it will work, but if you do hover over link1 and than over link2 it will not work`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var megaTrue=0; 
$('li.mega').mouseover(function() { 
    megaTrue = 1; 
}); 

$('li.mega').mouseout(function() { 
    megaTrue = 0; 
});
```

set megaTrue as a global var

Comment: How can I alert or log the change of the value of the variable?